# ADB doesn't detect the phone

Tags: adb

My device is stuck in bootloop and my USB debugging is disabled. When I type adb devices in CMD, it says adb is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. Please help

Comment: You need to install adb first before you can run it.

Comment: how can i install adb

Comment: Check my other comment with the link to a previously asked question

Comment: please give me the link of adb.I should dwonload it and install in pc

Comment: Please take a look into our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), @BenzJosuaESamson – what should get you started. You also will need the Windows drivers for your device. Still, all that will probably be useless if [usb-debugging](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info) isn't activated and you don't have a custom recovery installed, as ADB won't be able to see your device. Check our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) to first tackle your real issue, so you can enable USB Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

ADB is only accessible from recovery or a booted phone. When stuck in bootloop, reboot into bootloader and use the fastboot.exe instead. Then enter `fasboot reboot recovery` and continue via ADB

Comment: That would require a custom recovery installed. Stock recovery doesn't support ADB. Plus, according to the error message given by OP, the issue here is rather OP hasn't installed ADB tools on the computer used.

Answer (score -3):

If(custom ROM==true)
{
 - go to recovery mode from boot loader 
 - wipe data
 - wipe cache, delvik cache
 - reinstall a better rom
}
Else
- reset factory settings from rm

Comment: That doesn't install the ADB tools on a computer :) Read the error message again (the `adb` executable isn't found on OP's computer).